# dojox/mobile/SearchBox set text to empty (X Button) makes a view transition instead of cleaning text

Tags: cordova, dojo, dojox.mobile

I'm having the current situation: I have a SearchBox instance. When starting to type something, it appears on the right side of the input, a small icon symbol (with a X), to clear the text already written at the search input.

But, what happens instead is that I get a view transition. Did anyone have/had this problem?

I get this bug both in web browser (Safari, Chrome) and at the iOS (iPhone) version.

Comment: Can you put some code so we can see the layout.

Comment: Sorry i didn't answer back. I made a workaround. Basically, the problem was that, the onSearch method was being triggered even when you would press the clear button. So what i did was check if the input was empty. if so, fallback. And doesn't execute the code.

But it really seems bad design on the framework :\

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. Take for instance the native "Contacts" app on iOS. Touching the clear button triggers a refresh of the filtered list, and this sounds just logical. To allow implementing a similar behavior, dojox/mobile/SearchBox also needs to trigger the onSearch when the clear button is clicked/touched. Do I miss something?